# How to undo ~v (verbose) bash command?

Tags: bash, shell, logging, ssh

so I accidentally typed ~v in bash, and it changed LogLevel to Verbose.  I thought it might be a toggle, so I pressed it again and the Loglevel got set to DEBUG.  Now everything seems to be outputting debug info of some sort.  How do I disable this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~v` and `~V` are escape sequences used by the `ssh` client to increase and decrease, respectively, the logging level. To undo one (or more) increases, use `~V` the appropriate number of times. The various levels are

- QUIET
- FATAL
- ERROR
- INFO
- VERBOSE (the apparent default)
- DEBUG
- DEBUG1
- DEBUG2
- DEBUG3

Note the `~` is only an escape character if it is the first character pressed on a line. If you are instead just getting `~` on your command line, delete the line and hit Enter to start a fresh command line.

See the Escape Characters section of the `ssh` man page for more details.

Comment: Thanks.  The full list of levels is really helpful.

Comment: I forgot to mention where they are documented; see the `LogLevel` option in `ssh_config`. (Not that it gives any indication of what is logged at each level...)

Answer (score 1):

So, you stumbled upon an escape sequence in your `ssh` client (it has nothing to do with `bash`, or shell in general).

To decrease logging verbosity, type `~V`.

From `man ssh`:

> ```
> ~V    Decrease the verbosity (LogLevel) when errors are being written to stderr.
> ~v    Increase the verbosity (LogLevel) when errors are being written to stderr.
> ```

also available via `~?` escape sequence.

Few other interesting sequences:

> ```
> ~C    Open command line.  Currently this allows the addition of port forwardings using the -L, -R and -D options (see
>       above).  It also allows the cancellation of existing port-forwardings with -KL[bind_address:]port for local,
>       -KR[bind_address:]port for remote and -KD[bind_address:]port for dynamic port-forwardings.  !command allows the
>       user to execute a local command if the PermitLocalCommand option is enabled in ssh_config(5).  Basic help is avail‐
>       able, using the -h option.
> ~R    Request rekeying of the connection (only useful if the peer supports it).
> ```